# Understanding Spark Imputer

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I understand how an `imputer` is supposed to work, but I cannot fully understand the implementations of `imputer` in Spark. I expect a beginner-level explanation to the following code:

```
val results = $(strategy) match {
  case Imputer.mean =>
    // Function avg will ignore null automatically.
    // For a column only containing null, avg will return null.
    val row = dataset.select(cols.map(avg): _*).head()
    Array.range(0, $(inputCols).length).map { i =>
      if (row.isNullAt(i)) {
        Double.NaN
      } else {
        row.getDouble(i)
      }
    }

  case Imputer.median =>
    // Function approxQuantile will ignore null automatically.
    // For a column only containing null, approxQuantile will return an empty array.
    dataset.select(cols: _*).stat.approxQuantile($(inputCols), Array(0.5), 0.001)
      .map { array =>
        if (array.isEmpty) {
          Double.NaN
        } else {
          array.head
        }
      }
}
```

What I understand:

1. the logic of two strategies of an `imputer` in pseudo code.
2. basic scala & Spark dataframe.

What I do not understand in `Imputer.mean`:

1. Why do we have `val row` here? Why do we have .head()`?
2. How the missing value is imputed in `Imputer.mean`? I see how the average of each col is calculated, but I do not know how they get imputed. Is it by `row.getDouble(i)`
3. What is this `Array`? Where does it declared? Does it has any thing to do with `val row`?

What I do not understand in `Imputer.median`:

4. Don't we calculated median by `dataset.select(cols: _*).stat.approxQuantile($(inputCols), Array(0.5), 0.001)`? Why we have an `array` here? Why do we return the `array.head`?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have val row here?

Because it is descriptive name of variable as the type of the value is `Row`.

> Why do we have .head()`?

Because query alone returns `DataFrame` and we want the result of the query.

> How the missing value is imputed in Imputer.mean?

It is not. Imputation logic is implemented by [`ImputerModel.transform`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8d40a79a077a30024a8ef921781b68f6f7e542d1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/Imputer.scala#L214-L228)

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
  transformSchema(dataset.schema, logging = true)
  val surrogates = surrogateDF.select($(inputCols).map(col): _*).head().toSeq


  val newCols = $(inputCols).zip($(outputCols)).zip(surrogates).map {
    case ((inputCol, outputCol), surrogate) =>
      val inputType = dataset.schema(inputCol).dataType
      val ic = col(inputCol)
      when(ic.isNull, surrogate)
        .when(ic === $(missingValue), surrogate)
        .otherwise(ic)
        .cast(inputType)
  }
  dataset.withColumns($(outputCols), newCols).toDF()
}
```

> What is this Array

Because `Imputer` is designed to impute multiple values at once. So you need a collection of result, and `Row`, although collection-like, is not typed.

> Why we have an array here? Why do we return the array.head?

This is explained in detail, in the comment you copied into your question:

> ```
> For a column only containing null, approxQuantile will return an empty array.
> ```

Comment: `head` only returns the first row of the df. Can you explain why we only want the first row?